# Multiple selection possible drop down box and also an option to write other information

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have a requirement where there are some options that the user can select at a time. He can select a single or multiple options. Also there is an extra field called "Other" by selecting which the user can write his own information rather than selecting the options provided to him. I would like to design this requirement on a form in Access. I am really confused of what should the datatype be and how should the dropbox be designed. Please help me.

Comment: Without knowing your table structure, the only thing I can do is recommend that you use a list box (List boxes allow for multi-select). You can also have an unbound text box beneath or adjacent to your list box. After update of your list box, you can check if 'Other' is a selected value of your list box. If it is, make your unbound 'Other' text box visible for data entry. Whether you are going to concatenate your results or make separate entries after this depends on your design.

Comment: Thanks for the response Scotch. I have to yet create the table. So I am also looking for an effective way in which I can design it. I was thinking more of having a string datatype so that I can also concatenate the multiple options selected by the user. Can you please provide any pointers for the ListBox creation as you said.

Answer (score 1):

I'm already wary of the design as far as concatenating these values (your data should be as atomic as possible), but you could create your list box object, and in a button beside it or in after update, you could   do

```
dim values as string
dim item as variant
for each item in me!myListBox.ItemsSelected
values = values & me!myListBox.column(0, item) & ","
 next item
```

I posted this as an answer instead of a comment above so that the code snippet would be more readable.

Edit: I'm just seeing a red flag as far as design goes, it seems like what you want to accomplish would be better implemented using two tables with a one->many relationship. Instead of modeling the data with a multi-select listbox, your continuous subform would house this data.